# What is the easiest method to draw this on the screen using turtle graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

[image]

What would be the easiest method to draw this on the screen including colors?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Regular polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) might be helpful—especially section [2.1 Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Angles).

Comment: A simpler way than drawing all the segments manually would be to use [`turtle.circle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) and specify a small number of steps to get it to draw an inscribed regular polygon.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to answer this question without code, but if you know what the colored turtles are called, you can use:

```
[turtle name goes here].forward([distance])
```

to move that given turtle forward

```
[turtle name goes here].backward([distance])
```

to move it backward

```
[turtle name goes here].right([degrees/radians])
[turtle name goes here].left([degrees/ radians])
```

to turn the turtle right and left

for example:

```
#names the turtle Angie
Angie = Turtle()
#changes the color of Angie
Angie.color("blue")
#moves angie forward
Angie.forward(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, hope this helps! :-)

```
def polygon(length, sides, color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(360.0/sides)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(length*1.5)
    turtle.pendown()

polygon(100, 6, "green")
polygon(100, 3, "blue")
polygon(100, 4, "red")
```

Comment: On my screen, it appears the OP's polygons have a black outline so I would use `turtle.fillcolor(color)` instead of `turtle.color(color)`